# Angular service TypeError: Method is not a function, forcing lambda function instead of method

Tags: angular, typescript

I've never came across this error before and I'm unsure whether it's a typescript error or if I'm doing something wrong with Angular.

I have a class, that has the following method inside of it

```
assignTenantLocationDataToTable(tenant:Tenant): void {
    this.isLoadingTenantData = true;

    this._locationService.getLocationDataForTenantId(tenant.id).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyObservables)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

This method calls the `this._locationService.getLocationDataForTenantId()` method, in the location service. Which looks like this:

```
getLocationDataForTenantId(tenantId: string): Observable<Where[]> {
    const url = this._configService.getConfig().baseUrl +
      `${this._urlPrefix}/tenant/${tenantId}/locations`;

    return this._http.get<Where[]>(url, { observe: "response" })
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.body),
        catchError(err =>
          handleRequestErrors(
            err,
            this._noDataUIErrorMessage,
            this._snackbarService
          )
        )
      );
  }
```

However when I run this code, I'm given the following error:

```
VM46956 LocationsListComponent.ngfactory.js:262 ERROR TypeError: this._locationService.getLocationDataForTenantId is not a function
    at LocationsListComponent.assignTenantLocationDataToTable (VM46693 main.js:4888)
    at LocationsListComponent.changeSelectedTenant (VM46693 main.js:4884)
```

If I then change the `getLocationDataForTenantId` so that it is a lambda function, and therefore the signature looks like this

`getLocationDataForTenantId = (tenantId: string): Observable<Where[]> => { ... }`

The code works fine?

What gives? I've done plenty of typescript before and I've never came across this issue ever. Why can't I just call my method as I have been the rest of the time I've been using typescript?

I'm calling a method, within a component, which is then calling a second method within a service. Both of these methods are contained in classes, why is it forcing me to use a lambda?

Edit:

Tenent picker component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedTenant.emit(this.tenantListFormControl.value);
  }
```

Locations-list template

```
<app-tenant-picker
   [label]="getTranslateKey('tenants') | translate"
   (selectedTenant)="changeSelectedTenant($event)"
   (errorEmitter)="handleErrorEvent($event)">
</app-tenant-picker>
```

Locations list component

```
changeSelectedTenant(tenant: Tenant) {
    this.currentTenant = tenant;
    this.assignTenantLocationDataToTable(tenant);
  }

assignTenantLocationDataToTable(tenant:Tenant): void {
    this.isLoadingTenantData = true;

    this._locationService.getLocationDataForTenantId(tenant.id).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyObservables)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

Comment: There might be something that you haven't shared causing this problem. All looks well to me with limited visibility into the component.

Comment: @AndrewNolan I've added some more upstream to the method trace, is it anymore clear? What kind of thing could be causing this? Essentially what happens is there's a smaller component that makes a http call, then emits a value using an event emitter, that event it pushed to the locations list component which eventually makes the call to the location service